# AMQP MissedHeartbeatException

Tags: mule

AMQP connector shuts down with MissedHeartbeatException at regular intervals. Below is the connector configuration and exception stack.I am new to AMQP connector any suggestions are appreciated. 
I am using amqp transport 3.6.2 and mule server 3.7.2

AMQP Connector Config

```
<amqp:connector name="AMQP_Connector"
validateConnections="true" host="${amqp.host}" 
doc:name="AMQP Connector" virtualHost="${amqp.vhost}" 
password="${amqp.password}" port="${amqp.port}" 
username="${amqp.user}" numberOfChannels="1">
```

Exception Details

```
****************************************************************************
Message               : Connection shutdown detected for: AMQP_Connector
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 580 seconds (com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException)
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection:595 (null)
2. connection error (com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException)
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection:715 (null)
3. Connection shutdown detected for: AMQP_Connector  (org.mule.transport.ConnectException) org.mule.transport.amqp.internal.connector.AmqpConnector:321    (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 580 seconds
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleSocketTimeout(AMQConnection.java:595)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$600(AMQConnection.java:65)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:558)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
****************************************************************************
23:44:54.972     03/09/2016     Worker-0     pool-18-thread-1     INFO
Exception caught is a ConnectException, attempting to reconnect...
23:44:54.981     03/09/2016     Worker-0     pool-18-thread-1     INFO
Stopping connector: AMQP_Connector
23:44:54.983     03/09/2016     Worker-0     pool-18-thread-1     INFO
Stopping: 'AMQP_Connector.dispatcher.341143089'. Object is: Dispatcher
23:44:54.984     03/09/2016     Worker-0     pool-18-thread-1     INFO
Disposing: 'AMQP_Connector.dispatcher.341143089'. Object is: Dispatcher
23:44:54.985     03/09/2016     Worker-0     pool-18-thread-1     ERROR
connection is already closed due to connection error; cause: com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 580 seconds
```

Comment: Share your `AMQP` config

Comment: Hi Charu, I have added the AMQP connector config.